# How can i read image in vips like php imgick

Tags: vips

I am using php vips library. I want to readImage from filename in vips. I want to know that

```
$imagick->readImage() in php Imagick and 
Vips\Image::newFromFile($arg[1])
```

both are same? If no then is there any method in vips which is similar to `$imagick->readImage()

Comment: Yes, they will both read an image from a file. There are differences in the way they handle options, and when pixels are actually decoded.

Comment: One more thing, how can i convert my svg image to png using pvp vips?

Comment: In the obvious way: `$image = Vips\Image::newFromFile('something.svg', ['access' => 'sequential']); $image->writeToFile('x.png');`